# Switch between different languages interface in cakePhp

Tags: cakephp

I am learning the locale function in Cakephp.
I am not sure how to design my own locale files so that
users can switch between Spanish and English in my web sites.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first place I'd go is here, http://book.cakephp.org/view/162/Internationalizing-Your-Application

I've not tried this before, as the project I was working on, English and Swedish, someone had already done the setup.

From what I understand you can manage the language in your routes, to have `example.com/en/` or `example.com/se` then your other routes, and that will load up the correct language translations.

As I understand it there are multiple methods for managing how you switch the language from routes to sessions.